# Kill it with meteor strike: [home-network]

Tags: discussion

## A Senryu

There is little to dispute.

[home-network](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/home-network) must burninate.

**BURN! BURN! BURN! BURN! BURN!**

Comment: We *could* leave it as an insta-kill honeypot...

Answer (score 1):

Burninate it with NT CDs?
[image: Kill it with Microwaves!]